# strpos() returning seemingly random values

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I am trying to extract bits of a string.

The string looks like this:

```
$rowstr = "8:12-bk-16430|8:2012-bk-16430|1080751|7|||||10/30/2012|1/30/2012|||bk|||PINELLAS-FL|Tampa|Paid...
```

I get the first field just fine using this:

```
$pos1 = strpos($rowstr, "|") +1; //begining of field case number
$pos2 = strpos($rowstr, "|", $pos1 + 1); //end of field case number
$len1 = $pos2 - $pos1;  //string length
$field['case_num'][$i] = substr($rowstr,$pos1,$len1); // casenumber extracted
```

But when I try to extract the second field (should be `1080751`)

```
$pos3 = strpos($rowstr, "|", $pos2); //end of field 
$pos4 = strpos($rowstr, "|", $pos3 + 1); //end of field
$len2 = $pos3 - $pos4;  //string length
$field['field2'][$i] = substr($rowstr,$pos3,$len2); // field 2 extracted
```

The result is a very long string that starts with `|1080751|7|||||10/30/2012|10..`.

If `$pos3` returns `16` and `$pos4` returns `24` then why am I getting a result so much longer than 8 characters? Is PHP not counting special charters for some reason? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) ?

Comment: +1 for an easibly reproducable test case and a clear question

Comment: Why is `$pos3` returning `24`? The 24th character is a hyphen nowhere near what I'm looking for. Does PHP skip certain characters?

Comment: @Touki I think I'll give that a shot, this is too confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// Added + 1 here
$pos3 = strpos($rowstr, "|", $pos2) + 1; //end of field
$pos4 = strpos($rowstr, "|", $pos3 + 1); //end of field
// swapped $pos3 and $pos4 here
$len2 = $pos4 - $pos3;  //string length
$field['field2'][$i] = substr($rowstr,$pos3,$len2); // field 2 extracted
```

Comment: Definitely better, but now I'm returning `|7` instead of the actual second field. But this is workable. Thank you.

Comment: in `$pos3` yes, in others, no. I have it just the way you do in your answer.